# Submit form from modal

Tags: jquery

I have a form on a page, however, there's no submit. There's a link that launched a modal dialog using colorbox plugin. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

The link is actually in that dialog. Here's my code

**JS**

```
$('#openModal').colorbox({ 
    html: 'some text <input id="mySubmit" type="button" value="submit form">' 
});

$('#mySubmit').click(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="openModal">open modal</div>

</form>
```

Does not seem to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `.click()` before your button is included in the dom. Use event delegation instead: `.delegate()` http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$(document).delegate('#mySubmit', 'click', function() {
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Add `console.log` or `alert` call and confirm at least the event is firing. If that's not the case, then validate you use correct ids/name and validate you don't have any duplicate if in your page.

Comment: Oh, and, document without `"`

Comment: Just added alert and it's not coming up... Weird.

Comment: OK, took out '' from around document and it seems to fire up alert :)